# How to tell if webcam can capture audio as well?

Tags: c#, uwp, audio-recording

I have little desktop app which uses UWP API to capture data from webcam (`MediaCapture`). On my computer it works fine -- I can capture video and audio. When I run the same program on the other computer it crashes -- as I found out I had to disable audio recording:

```
var media_settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
// audio+video by default
media_settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Video;

await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(media_settings);
```

Is there a way to find out in advance if given webcam supports audio recording? By "in advance" I mean the other way than trying, catching exception and in second take disabling audio :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if the given webcam supports audio recording by enumerating the audio devices before you initialize the [`MediaCaptureInitializationSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacaptureinitializationsettings) object. After finishing enumerating the audio device, you can find whether there is a audio device from the webcam or not.

You can follow the [Enumerate devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices) topic or see the [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) sample directly to find the **AudioCapture** device, then you should be able to judge if there is a audio device from the webcam.

Comment: I thought about it, but the problem is then when I enumerate for video I get some name like "Live Webcam", and when I enumerate audio I get "Live Microphone". I see as human see they are related but relaying on name format (there is none) is not reliable.

Comment: @astrowalker  it seems to be  a headache to select the correct Microphone from the enumeration result in the code. What about to show all the audio devices then make the user to select it?

Comment: I would like to avoid bothering user, in worst case I use try-catch approach :-).